# javascript script block is not rendered in django template

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to pull a from via ajax on the "current.html"

The view that handles the form renders "form.html"

"current.html" is something like:

```
<script>
    // ajax that pulls the form on a#get_form click 
    // fills up div#mod_post with the result 
</script>

<a id="get_form" href="{% url to the view that handles the form %}">get form</a>

<div id="mod_post" style="display:none;">
    {% include "form.html" %}
</div>
```

All good until here ... the form is nicely retrieved and shown.

"form.html" is something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/the/script/that/should/handle/the/post.js"></script>

<form id="mod_form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <table class="form">
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="modifica">
</form>
```

Only thing is that everytime when form.html is being rendered, it never contains the part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/the/script/that/should/handle/the/post.js">
</script>
```

Am I doing something wrong here, obviously yes, but I cannot spot it.

Any feedback is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just straight dumping the HTML response via JavaScript, then that's normal behavior. Your browser (i.e. all of them) auto-strips `<script>` tags added to the page by JS via an arbitrary HTML string response as a security precaution.

Comment: I guess this is what's happening since my ajax success function loads the result in a div (adiv.html(result)); 

Is there any workaround for this? I would try what rantanplan suggested, but I am not extending my base template ...

Comment: I can't think of an *easy* way to get around it. You *could* JSON encode the form object and include that along with the URL to the JavaScript in the response, then actually create the form and script tag manually with JS. However, I'd strongly recommend just including the form JS in your main JS file, or any page-specific JS that is already loaded.

Comment: well I realized that the scripts are not shown in firebug for example, but if i read the source, the scripts are there ... however i noticed that if i assign for the script a charset attribute to utf-8, everything seems to be ok .. in IE7 as well :)

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to encapsulate relevant js/css scripts within your form.
e.g.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = ...
    field2 = ...
    class Media:
        js = ('script_that_handles_the_form.js',)
```

In your `base.html` have a block like:

```
{% block scripts %}
  <!--- some scripts that apply to all pages -->
{% endblock %}
```

and then in your `form.html`

```
{% block scripts %}
  {{ block.super }}    # retain the standard scripts that apply everywhere
  {{ form.media }}     # add the form specific media/scripts
{% endblock %}

<form id="mod_form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <table class="form">
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="modifica">
</form>
```